# Как умножить матрицу 3x3 на 3x1 на языке С

Tags: c, массивы

```
double s[3][3] = {-0.145, 0.784,  0.745,
                  0.214, 0.547,  0.547,
                  0.321, 0.254,  0.452 };

double g[3] = {0.124,0.245,0.657};

double result[3];

int i, j; 

int main() {
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        result[i] += s[i][j] * g[i];
        result[i];
        printf("%d\t", result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что не правильно я написал в программе? В итоге должен получить матрицу 3x1.

Comment: Как минимум, не инициализирован `result`.

Comment: result[i] += s[i][j] * g[j];

Comment: переменная глобальный массив, должен быть 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Внутри цикла по j индекс g должен меняться.

```
int main() {
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result[i]=0;//для верности
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){ 
        result[i] += s[i][j] * g[j];
    }
    printf("%d\t", result[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()

double s[3][3] =
{
    {-0.145, 0.784,  0.745},
    {0.214, 0.547,  0.547},
    {0.321, 0.254,  0.452}
};

double g[3] = {0.124,0.245,0.657};

double result[3];



int main( void )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            result[i] += s[i][j] * g[i];
            //result[i];
            printf("%f\t", result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
-0.017980   0.079236    0.171616    0.052430    0.186445    0.320460    0.210897    0.377775    0.674739
```